# Vue Adding/Removing Classes - Reactive Boolean vs ID

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

### Scenario

SignalR informs a listener of changes which need reflecting on the UI. When the underlying data changes we inform non-visually impaired users of the change by adding an animation effect before removing it 3 seconds later.

### Question

Which of the following '***Code Options***' is considered best practice when adding/removing the animation effect? Alternatively, is there another option I've not considered which might be better? Or, should it be situational?

### Personal Considerations

The '***Boolean***' option feels cleaner but it's one more element being watched on a reactive object, and a lot of these are likely to change in one fell swoop. If we manually modify the DOM without using a reactive object it might save on some overhead but it doesn't feel as clean.

### Code Options

**Update Class on Boolean**

```js
connection
    .on("EventName", (response: ResponseModel) => {
        const foo = this.FooArray
            .find((fooDetails: FooArrayModel) => fooDetails.Id === response.Id);

        foo.Name = response.Name;
        foo.HasUpdated = true;

        setTimeout(() => {
            foo.HasUpdated = false;
        }, 3000);
    });
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <template v-for="foo in FooArray" :key="foo.Id">
        <div class="cell" aria-live="polite" :class="{ 'animation-class': foo.HasUpdated }">{{foo.Name}}</div>
    </template>
</div>
```

**Update Class on ID**

```js
connection
    .on("EventName", (response: ResponseModel) => {
        const foo = this.FooArray
            .find((fooDetails: FooArrayModel) => fooDetails.Id === response.Id);

        foo.Name = response.Name;

        const element = document.getElementById(foo.Id);
        element.classList.add("animation-class");

        setTimeout(() => {
            element.classList.remove("animation-class");
        }, 3000);
    });
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <template v-for="foo in FooArray" :key="foo.Id">
        <div class="cell" aria-live="polite" :id="foo.Id">{{foo.Name}}</div>
    </template>
</div>
```